# Can we add a new user to opensips using rest_client?

Tags: voip, telephony, opensips

Can we a new user using opensips rest_client?
If yes then what i have to add to the config file.
If not then is there any other module using which i can communicate to opensips from an external system?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to provision data for the OpenSIPS tables:

1. web GUI (OpenSIPS Control Panel)
2. HTTP requests (with the pi_http + httpd modules [1])

I can see that **2.** seems to suit you best. The involved module is named "auth_db", table "subscriber".

[1] : http://www.opensips.org/html/docs/modules/1.12.x/pi_http.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new user directly to the DB. I use a stored procedure (MySQL) similar to below:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `ADD_SUBS`(IN subid VARCHAR(64),INOUT pwd VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
DECLARE realm , ha1 , ha1b VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT 'your.sip.domain';
DECLARE res INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT count(id) into res  from subscriber where `username` = subid;

if res = 0 then
 set ha1 = md5(concat(subid ,':',realm,':',pwd));
 set ha1b = md5(concat(subid,'@',realm,':',realm,':',pwd));

 INSERT INTO subscriber (`username`,`domain`,`password`,`ha1`,`ha1b`) VALUES (subid, realm, pwd, ha1, ha1b);
end if;
```